# Which academic subjects examine what the advantages and disadvantages of the various number bases are?

Tags: number-theory

Which academic subjects examine what the advantages and disadvantages of the various number bases are, e.g. besides base ten: base twelve, base sixteen, base eight, base two and the ways that they can be written and pronounced.

For example, base eight 10001 can be pronounced "one zero zero zero one base eight", "four thousand ninety-six one", "two to the power twelve one", and some other ways, and there is no consensus about which way is best. Would this be a mathematical question, or a cognitive science question, a mathematical education question or some other kind of question?

For another example, to what academic subject does the question of how to write thirty-six in base thirty-seven belong?

Answer (score 3):

> Which academic subjects examine what the advantages and disadvantages of the various number bases are, e.g. besides base ten: base twelve, base sixteen, base eight, base two and the ways that they can be written and pronounced.

I don't know whether this has been investigated academically. You should use Semantic scholar, Google scholar and other academic search engines for this purpose.

But: It is not so that any given question necessarily is part of a fixed academic subject, or any of them. Academia does not work this way. If someone has researched, or will research, this question, then they would search for an academic journal that would accept the result and write the paper for it. The particular would depend on the precise research question, but also the background of the author.

On the other hand, this could also be something like bachelor's or master's thesis, which would be nominally under some academic field, but the connection might be very nominal. Or it might be a side issue in a PhD thesis or some book etc.

> For another example, to what academic subject does the question of how to write thirty-six in base thirty-seven?

From a mathematical perspective, the list of number symbols could be extended in an arbitrary way. Consider hexadecimals for an example of how this has been done. Since this does not have clear applications (as far as I know), and all the ways of doing this are mathematically equivalent anyway, I doubt people have bothered to think about this. The relevant academic subject depends on who needs such notation; developing it would presumably be a side effect of whatever it is being developed for.

Comment: "Four-score and seven years ago" is how the famous Gettysburg Address begins. This phrase is vocabulary from the vigesimal numeral system, which is base twenty.

Comment: @user52817 For less obscure examples, see the Danish and the French number systems.